# Wordpress won't display custom php file,

Tags: php, wordpress, url

MY website is in wordpress.
I have file `api.php` that is placed in same folder as `index.html` 
But when i do `mysite.com/api.php` it redirects to wordpress page that no page is found.

Is there a way to access custom php file (e.g `api.php`) through url ?

Comment: it's not recommanded to use a direct acces to a PHP file. it's better to use instead AJAX (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or REST (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

Comment: there are special URL rewriting rules in Wordpress for you to be able to access your site via `mysite.com/anyContentUrl` through `index.html`. But if you want to access to a custom file, you have to precise the full URL, for example for your theme `mysite.com/wp-content/themes/yourTheme/file.php`. If you don't want this path to be shown, place it in another folder in your site root for example (and still access it with its full URL)

Comment: Please check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39765/how-to-add-a-php-file-to-wordpress which is similar to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Place your file to root of wordpress  directory,where wp-config file exist. Clear cache and try to access your file via url.

Answer (score 1):

Place your file(api.php) to root of wordpress  directory,where wp-config.php file exist.

Clear cache and try to access your file via url.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create folder at your website root directory
like:
wp-admin
wp-content
wp-yourfolder/yourfile.php,
than in yourfile.php include

include('wp-config.php');
and do what you want like

$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_date, ID  FROM $wpdb->posts  WHERE post_status = 'publish' ");
```

Comment: Its not even letting me access subfolder.(wp-yourfolder)

Comment: @user3603023 do you have a plugin to protect some folders access? or a plugin for security more generally?

Comment: Refer to this toturial:
  http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/9-most-useful-htaccess-tricks-for-wordpress/